# Is it possible to implement a splashscreen in Ren'Py?

Tags: python, splash-screen, renpy

Is it still possible to implement a splashscreen in the latest version of Ren'Py? I have searched through every forum concerning the use of splashscreens; however, all of them are either outdated or do not work. Below I included the snippet of code from the historic Ren'Py wiki page (which does not work in the newest version). I couldn't find any other official documentation on the Ren'Py site. At this point, I'm a little desperate. How in the world can I do this?

```
label splashcreen:
  scene black
  with pause (1.0)

  show text "splash text" with dissolve
  with pause (2.0)

  hide text with dissolve
  with pause (1.0)

return
```

Comment: Have you try with `label splashscreen:`instead of `label splashcreen:`? It seem there is a typo error in your code (a `s` was omitted)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of spelling. Check the spelling of splashscreen. You forgot the third 's'. splashScreen, not splashcreen. Also, you don't need the with pause, just use pause. Here's the code with the proper changes. I tested it on the latest version of Ren'Py (7.3.2).

```
label splashscreen:
     scene black
     pause 1.0

     show text "splash text" with dissolve
     pause 2.0

     hide text with dissolve
     pause 1.0

     return
```

Comment: This question is about help with implementation. If you are not answering the question, please add your message as a comment.

Comment: I added more details to my answer. Ty for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the *splash screen* before the menu, right?

If so, try:

```
label splashscreen: # create a label for your splashscreen

    play music mysong # This is optional
    scene black
    with Pause(5) # You can change the pause time

    show text "Lorem Ipsum..." with dissolve
    with Pause(5)
    hide text with dissolve
    with Pause (1)
    show text "My" with dissolve # You can change this to an image if you have one
    with Pause(6) # This pauses the current shown text
    hide text with dissolve
    with Pause(2)

return # And of course the Return will take you to the main menu screen
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image shown while Ren'py is reading the scripts and launching the game, you can use the presplash feature of Renpy.

To show such and image while the engine is starting up, create an image file named presplash.png (or presplash.jpg), and save it into the game directory.